# SED (linux) issue with recursive

Tags: php, command-line, sed

I'm trying to replace the string `$PHP_SELF` by `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in all `php` files. I've ran this command, but it simply remove the string and replace by nothing:

```
cd /home/rg/public_html && find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i.php -pe "s/\\\$PHP_SELF/\$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']/g"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use gnu `sed/grep/xargs`, such as:

```
$ cd /home/rg/publick_html
$ find . | grep "[.]php$" | xargs sed -e 's/\$PHP_SELF/\$_SERVER\['PHP_SELF'\]/g'  -i
```

also:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" | xargs sed -e 's/\$PHP_SELF/\$_SERVER\['PHP_SELF'\]/g'  -i
```

thanks @Utopik

good luck~

Comment: `find . -type f -name "*.php" | xargs [...]` is better

Comment: Yes , indeed.  I used to grep..  :)